# SharedPreferences подружить с веб-приложением webView

Tags: javascript, android, webview

Пишу веб-приложение на связке php/js/html, и через Andriod Studio конвертирую его в приложение для плеймаркета.

Для хранения небольших данных испльзую local.storage в js
И что бы приложение могло записать что либо в local.storage
открываю в манифесте доступ к записи/чтению

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Но мне нужно только хранить одну строку с данными (ключ)
Всё остальное идёт как обычный сайт c обменом данными js-php через ajax

Но пользователи, которые устанавливают приложение, у них идёт запрос "разрешите чтение/запись файлов на ваше устройство". (так как стоит запрос доступа).

Я хочу этого избежать, и слышал что в андроиде есть SharedPreferences - некое место куда можно записать небольшие данные без запроса доступа.

Вопрос:
можно ли как-то это использовать для обычных веб приложений, что бы избежать запроса на чтение/запись?
Спасибо.

UPD:
Нашел переходник, как использовать в js Android SharedPreferences
Как я понял - это то что мне нужно, использовать Android SharedPreferences в интерфейсе javascript в вебприложении

Вот ссылка на гитхаб
https://github.com/paolorotolo/JSharedPreferences

Но при установке той части которая идет в mainactivity
14-ая строка выдает ошибку:

```
  mStorage = c.getSharedPreferences(c.getResources().getString(R.string.key_file), 0);
```

а именно светиться красным key_file.

Помогите с этим разобраться.
Код из гитхаба написал 4 года назад, может что-то уже не актульно и работает не так как нужно?

Answer (score 0):

`c.getResources().getString(R.string.key_file)` - это получение строки из ресурсов (которой у Вас нет).
Вы можете добавить её нажав на красную лампочку, выскакивающую на ошибке и выбрав соответствующее предложение, либо вписать ручками в файл [(документация)](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/string-resource#String).
Или просто заменить на текстовую константу:

```
mStorage = c.getSharedPreferences("my_pref_file_name", 0);
```

То есть в этом выражении строка задаёт имя файла преференсов и определять её в ресурсах не обязательно.

P.S. Я с такой задачей не сталкивался, но мне кажется что для local.storage в js, `WebView` должна использовать приватное хранилище, разрешение на доступ к которому не требуется. Может быть Вы не правильно задали настройки (`WebSettings`)?

Comment: Спасибо за наводку. Попробую разобраться с приватным хранилищем. Мне тоже кажется что всё должно быть гораздо проще